# Why does IE10 say `Object doesn't support property or method 'appendchild'`

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have the following code in my **JavaScript** file :

```
col1.appendchild(X);
```

where `x` is an object and I am appending the entire thing to a tree. 
When I check the `developer console` in `IE10`, It says `Object doesn't support property or method 'appendchild'` 
The same code seems to be working just fine on `IE10` on a different Computer but not this one.
Any suggestions on how to get along with it are much appreciated!

Comment: "The same code seems to be working just fine on IE10 on a different Computer but not this one" Considering VisionN's answer, how is that possible?

Comment: @atmd IE was always full of mystery.

Comment: I made a typo :) thanks for the help though. @atmd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive language. The correct name of the method is `appendChild`.

**MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild